# Rails 4 - Messenger gem - tutorial setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, messenger

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I'm trying to follow this tutorial to setup the messenger gem.    http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/private-inbox-system-in-rails-with-mailboxer

I have:

Gemfile:

```
gem "mailboxer"
```

User.rb

```
def mailboxer_name
  self.full_name
end

def mailboxer_email(object)
  self.email
end
```

mailboxer.rb initialiser

```
config.email_method = :mailboxer_email
config.name_method = :full_name
```

I have an attribute in my user table called :email and I have a method in my user model called:

```
def full_name
  if first_name.present?
    [*first_name.capitalize, last_name.capitalize].join(" ")
  else 
    test full name
  end    
end
```

One difference between this attempt and the tutorial is that since I previously tried the site point tutorial (and couldn't get it working), I already have a messages controller and view folder in my app. Where this tutorial users 'mailbox', I use 'messages'

I can't get past the first test point in this tutorial. I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in MessagesController#inbox
undefined method `inbox' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

The error message highlights this method:

```
def inbox
  @inbox = messages.inbox
  @active = :inbox
end
```

I have:

messages controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def inbox
    @inbox = messages.inbox
    @active = :inbox
  end

  def sent
    @sent = messages.sentbox
    @active = :sent
  end

  def trash
    @trash = messages.trash
    @active = :trash
  end
end
```

application helper

```
def flash_class(level)
  case level.to_sym
    when :notice then "alert alert-success"
    when :info then "alert alert-info"
    when :alert then "alert alert-danger"
    when :warning then "alert alert-warning"
  end
end

def active_page(active_page)
  @active == active_page ? "active" : ""
end
```

messages helper

```
def unread_messages_count
  # how to get the number of unread messages for the current user
  # using mailboxer
  messages.inbox(:unread => true).count(:id, :distinct => true)
end
```

messages views folder has:

_folder_view.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <!-- we'll configure this to compose new conversations later -->
    <%= link_to "Compose", "#", class: "btn btn-success" %>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= render 'messages/folders' %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <!-- individual conversations will show here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
view raw
```

_folders.html.erb

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li class="<%= active_page(:inbox) %>">
    <%= link_to messages_inbox_path do  %>
        <span class="label label-danger pull-right"><%=unread_messages_count%></span>
        <em class="fa fa-inbox fa-lg"></em>
        <span>Inbox</span>
    <% end %>
  </li>
  <li class="<%= active_page(:sent) %>">
    <%= link_to messages_sent_path do %>

        <em class="fa fa-paper-plane-o fa-lg"></em>
        <span>Sent</span>
    <% end %>
  </li>

  <li class="<%= active_page(:trash) %>">
    <%= link_to messages_trash_path do %>
        <em class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></em>
        <span>Trash</span>
    <% end %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

each of inbox.html.er, sent.html.erb and trash.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'messages/folder_view' %>
```

routes.rb

```
get "messages/inbox" => "messages#inbox", as: :messages_inbox
  get "messages/sent" => "messages#sent", as: :messages_sent
  get "messages/trash" => "messages#trash", as: :messages_trash
```

Application controller:

```
helper_method :messages

  private


  def messages
    @messages ||= current_user.messages
  end
```

Can anyone see where I've gone wrong?

I'm up to tutorial step that says: Clicking the inbox link should take you to our up and running inbox page with navigation already in place for the inbox, sent and trash folders.

Instead, I get an error message that says:

```
NoMethodError in MessagesController#inbox
undefined method `inbox' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Can anyone see what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've forgot to add helper method *messages* to *ApplicationController* as it made in tutorial:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # [...]
  helper_method :messages

  private

  def messages
    @messages ||= current_user.mailbox
  end

  protected

  # [...]
end
```

**Update 1**

I see that in your helper you have current_user.**messages** in should be current_user.**mailbox**

Comment: Hi - no - I have it.

Comment: in this case so does  current.user.mailbox work fine? Do you get any errors?

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: @user2860931 I've found a mistake in you help method and I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks - I wansn't sure if that needed to match my model or the actual gem. Thanks very much